# Getting ADB to work in Ubuntu

Tags: android, bash, ubuntu-11.10, android-sdk-2.3

After searching around throughout the net, it seems like the issue of the operating system not being to recognize the `adb` tool, or any other platform tool (for that matter), has been common.

What I'm hoping to understand is that, if one were to modify their `~/.profile` so it resembled the following:

```
 20 if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
 21     PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/android-sdks/platform-tools:$PATH"
 22 fi
```

Why is it that the `adb` is still not recognized, even when (while in the relevant directory of course), I do a `./adb`?

Comment: Does `$HOME/bin` exist? What is the output of `test -x $HOME/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb && echo OK || echo FAIL`? If you `echo $PATH` do you see what you added to the `$PATH`? (in some cases you might have to log out and log back in)

Comment: Why don't you just put it in your export it to your PATH directory instead of using a script... ?

Answer (score 2):

I would check and see if you have a `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`, which would take precedence if you are using Bash.

I personally use this in `~/.bash_profile`

```
# --- add Android platform-tools directory
PATH=~/android-sdks/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

Please update the *PATH* in **/etc/profile**

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/user/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools:/home/user/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms:/home/user/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools
export PATH
```

I personally use this in **/etc/profile** this will work for any user.

Hope this will help you.